# Query on Kerberized HBase hangs

Tags: java, hbase, kerberos, cloudera

I have a web server which is presenting some data from a Cloudera cluster. The data are stored on HBase and the cluster is secured with Kerberos. When I try to perform a get, the server hangs without logging any error.

So far I've tried:

1. Launching the webserver from command line after a `kinit` (the server is just for testing purpose, so log-in duration and complex procedures to start it are not an issue)
2. The `runAs` approach described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561736/java-client-for-secure-hbase), both with and without the configuration file import from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655253/3110448).
3. The `CLASSPATH` configuration approach described [here](https://scalding.io/2015/02/making-your-hbase-client-work-in-a-kerberized-environment/)
4. Global authentication with `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab` (with and without all the configurations from point 2 and 3)

I've executed all the gets from `hbase shell` after `kinit`ing with the web server's user and they work in reasonable time (less than a second, while the last time I left the connection open the server didn't respond in over an hour), so it's not a performance or authorization issue. Inside the same web server, with every configuration listed, I'm able to perform other actions, like connecting to HBase and getting the table instances.

I've also checked the logs from Kerberos, HBase and my web server and none of them presents any error. In fact, I'm pretty much afraid that the authorization works, but it just gets stuck in some loop during the get.

UPDATES: After more testing, I've verified that there is a user set right before the call to HBase's API. Also, I've checked and *no calls* are made to HBase. So this is not an authentication problem, but something else. Did anybody have the same problem?

Comment: You can always examine your tickets with `klist`, and check that you have allocation for hbase in any [*service pools*](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/admin_rm.html) you're using. Also, do you have a `keytab` file setup?

Comment: I've used the same `keytab` both from Java and in the command line, and it work from the command line (I've checked with `klist` and when I'm using the `keytab` I only have one ticket), so the setup works. HBase also works without issues whether I use it from the shell or from spark, it's just the web server that gets stuck.

Comment: _"no calls are made to HBase"_ > what did you check, actually -- the client-side logs, with Log4J at DEBUG level? the existence and status of TCP connections on client side, with `ss` or `netstat`? the server-side logs (ZK, HBase Master, HBase RegionServers)?

Comment: I've checked both the server side logs, which don't register anything as incoming, and the thread stack, which shows the thread as asleep before sending the query.