# Connect to Kerborised Hbase tables from Java

Tags: java, hbase, kerberos

I am using below configuration to connect from java code to kerborised hbase tables.

```
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", zookeeperHosts);
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", zookeeperPort);
config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
config.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(ZOOKEEPER_PRINCIPAL,ZOOKEEPER_KEYTAB)
```

I am trying to **`Get`**  data from Hbase .
On running java code ,after creating **`Connection` and Table** , the code get paused with out showing any errors .
       If I remove the kerberose part and run it in a non kerborised env , I am able to connect to Hbase and Get tables . I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24737373/1559331) link , but didn't work.

Comment: You are may be missing master and region server kerberos principals. Could you put all the used code please ?

Comment: I have added that and tried , but that didn't work

Comment: One doubt is , what should be the principal and ketab to give , is that specific to user or zookeeper

Comment: It's the HBase user credentials. Try first with kinit .. and hbase shell